# Exception thrown on pool.close() while debugging, but not while running

Tags: python, pycharm, python-multiprocessing

I don't think I encountered this problem working on this in Python 2.7, but while debugging in 3.7, Python throws an exception when `pool.close()` is called. This is the relevant part of the function:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
iterator = pool.imap_unordered(worker_func, worker_input)

while True:
    try:
        t0, t1 = next(iterator)
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        dbinserts1(t0)
        dbinserts2(t1)            

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The only change made by `2to3` was rewriting `iterator.next()` as  `next(iterator)`. The function only fails while debugging (in PyCharm), otherwise it runs successfully. This is (probably) the most relevant part of the stack trace:

> Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>    "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py",
>   line 322, in _exit_function
>       p.join()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py",
>   line 138, in join
>       assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
>   AssertionError: can only join a child process

Comment: How are you debugging? Are you using a python debugger? (pdb)

Comment: @dm03514 Sorry, I tagged it PyCharm but didn't specify that in the question. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which PyCharm version do you use? This seems to be fixed in 2019.1.2 by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34436

Comment: Yes, this was just released hours ago, but it fixes it!