# Python throws error when breakpoint is set, works normal otherwise

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pytorch

I will just list my setup before I give details about my problem:
PyCharm EDU, Python 3.7.3, PyTorch 1.1.0 and a GeForce2080 TI.

I've downloaded an implementation of PointNet for PyTorch and just added a dataloader to fit my data format.
PointNet Code:
https://github.com/fxia22/pointnet.pytorch
PointNet Paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00593

It's working fine, however, if I set any breakpoints in my code, python throws an error from time to time before it stops working at all. It seems that some thread breaks for some reason:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _DataLoaderIter.__del__ at 0x7fdf32f30378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py"
        self._shutdown_workers()
    File site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py"
        w.join()
    File /multiprocessing/process.py"
        assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
AssertionError: can only join a child process
```

This ONLY happens if a breakpoint is set.
If I remove the breakpoint, there are no errors at all.
If I start the script without breakpoints and place a breakpoint at some point during the execution, it throws the error message shortly after I did so.

It is not really critical as I can just remove breakpoints and everything works fine, nonetheless I would like to know what's causing this error and how to fix it probably.

I did a search on the net, but I couldn't find anything describing the same problem I'm facing right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception thrown on pool.close() while debugging, but not while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929554/exception-thrown-on-pool-close-while-debugging-but-not-while-running)